# How to fix adding entites to ManyToMany after registration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, nullpointerexception, spring-data

I need to check if user's email is already added to list of students and if so, connect this user with course.

I've already checked all references and other, but I still get NullPointer

**User Entity**

```
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Student_Courses",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "course_id")}
    )
    private Set<Course> availableCourses;
```

**Course Entity**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "availableCourses")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

**CourseStudentEmails(*entries of student emails in course*)**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", nullable = false)
    private Course course;

    private String email;
```

**CourseService**

```
public void bindStudentWithCoursesAfterRegistration(String email) {

        User user = userRepo.findFirstByEmail(email);
        List<CourseStudentEmails> studentEntriesInCourses = courseStudentEmailsRepo.findAllByEmail(email);

        if (studentEntriesInCourses != null){
            Set<Course> availableCourses = new HashSet<>();

            for (CourseStudentEmails entry : studentEntriesInCourses) {
                availableCourses.add(entry.getCourse());
            }
            user.setAvailableCourses(availableCourses);//nullpointer is here
            userRepo.save(user);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize your Set before use it, try :

```
private Set<Course> availableCourses = new HashSet<>();
```

or

```
public void addAvailableCourse(Course course){
    this.availableCourses = new HashSet<>();
    this.availableCourses.add(course);
    course.getUsers().add(this);
}
```

Comment: I`ve done, but it stiil doesn't work. Check my edited question

Comment: then your user is null, so maybe the `email` value is not in database. Check your method `userRepo.findFirstByEmail(email);`

Comment: if your problem is solved, then can you answer and close the question ?